# Include variable value in validation message

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, annotations

If I have this variable in my Java model:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", message = "Unsupported characters for 'myVariable'")
private String myVariable;
```

Is it possible to include the value of myVariable in the message? E.g. if myVariable was 'foo!' the message might read "'foo' is unsupported for 'myVariable'".

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validation-message-interpolation).

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", message="'${validatedValue}' contains unsupported characters")
private String myVariable;
```