# Customize spring boot starter validation error message with the given value

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I wrote a DTO class to pass certain values to an endpoint. To sanitize the passed parameters I am using spring boot starter validation but I would like the error message handled by a Handler to return a message containing the value that was used as input.

Can this be done directly or do I have to implement special methods?

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class ForecastWeatherParametersDTO {

    @NotNull
    @Max(value = 90, message = "Latitude must be in range of -90 to 90°. Given: {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    @Min(value = -90, message = "Latitude must be in range of -90 to 90°. Given: {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    private Double latitude;

    @NotNull
    @Max(value = 180, message = "Longitude must be in range of -180 to 180°. Given: {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    @Min(value = -180, message = "Longitude must be in range of -180 to 180°. Given: {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    private Double longitude;

    @Builder.Default
    private List<HourlyForecastVariablesEnum> hourly = new ArrayList<>();
    @Builder.Default
    private List<DailyForecastVariablesEnum> daily = new ArrayList<>();
    @Builder.Default
    private List<ModelsForecastEnum> models = List.of(ModelsForecastEnum.BEST_MATCH);

    // setting
    @JsonProperty("past_days")
    @Builder.Default
    @Max(value = 92, message = "Past days is invalid. Allowed range 0 to 92. Given {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Past days is invalid. Allowed range 0 to 92. Given {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    private Integer pastDays = 0;

    @JsonProperty("future_days")
    @Builder.Default
    @Max(value = 16, message = "Forecast days is invalid. Allowed range 0 to 16. Given {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Forecast days is invalid. Allowed range 0 to 16. Given {INSERT_GIVEN_VALUE}.")
    private Integer futureDays = 7;

    @JsonProperty("temperature_unit")
    @Builder.Default
    private TemperatureUnitEnum temperatureUnit = TemperatureUnitEnum.CELSIUS;

    @JsonProperty("windspeed_unit")
    @Builder.Default
    private WindSpeedUnitEnum windSpeedUnit = WindSpeedUnitEnum.KMH;

    @JsonProperty("precipitation_unit")
    @Builder.Default
    private PrecipitationUnitEnum precipitationUnit = PrecipitationUnitEnum.MM;

    @JsonProperty("time_format")
    @Builder.Default
    private TimeFormatEnum timeFormat = TimeFormatEnum.ISO8601;

    @Builder.Default
    @JsonProperty("time_zone")
    private TimeZoneEnum timeZone = TimeZoneEnum.GMT0;

}
```

Comment: Try `${validatedValue}` as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735952/include-variable-value-in-validation-message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the Unified Expression Language. Example based on your sample code:

```
@Max(value = 16, message = "Forecast days is invalid. Allowed maximum of {value}. Given ${validatedValue}.")
```